# Adding summary row to dplyr output

Tags: r, dplyr

I found a few solutions on here but none seem to work to add a summary row to dplyr output.

```
 #mock up data
 df <- data.frame("Market" = sample(c("East", "North", "West"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.33, 0.33, 0.34)),
             "var1" = sample(c("Y", "N"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.6)),
             "var2" = sample(c("Y", "N"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
             "var3" = sample(c("Y", "N"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5)))
```

Here is the code:

```
 df_report <- df %>%
   group_by(Market) %>%
   filter(Market == "East" | Market == "West") %>%
   summarise(n = n(),
        var1_y = sum(var1 == "Y"),
        var1_n = sum(var1 == "N")) %>%
   mutate(total = var1_y + var1_n,
     var1_y_pct = (var1_y/total),
     var1_n_pct = (var1_n/total),
     pct_total = total/sum(total))
```

Here is the output:

```
 # A tibble: 2 x 8
   Market     n var1_y var1_n total var1_y_pct var1_n_pct pct_total
   <fct>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 East      29     13     16    29      0.448      0.552     0.453
 2 West      35     16     19    35      0.457      0.543     0.547
```

Here are the two solutions I tried:

## Option 1

```
 df_report %>%
    add_row(Market = "Total", n = sum(n), var1_y = sum(var1_y), var1_n = sum(var1_n), 
 total = sum(total), var1_y_pct = sum(var1_y_pct), var1_n_pct = sum(varn_y_pct), pct_total = sum(pct_total))
```

## Option 2

```
 df_report %>%
   rbind(c("Total", sum(n), sum(var1_y), sum(var1_n), sum(total), sum(var1_y_pct), sum(varn_y_pct), sum(pct_total)))
```

Both give me the same error:  *Error in sum(n) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument*

I'm unable to determine why these solutions, while working for others and seeming very reasonable, are not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```
df_report %>% janitor::adorn_totals("row")
```

Which produces

```
 Market  n var1_y var1_n total var1_y_pct var1_n_pct pct_total
   East 30     11     19    30  0.3666667  0.6333333 0.4285714
   West 40     19     21    40  0.4750000  0.5250000 0.5714286
  Total 70     30     40    70  0.8416667  1.1583333 1.0000000
```

The long way of doing this is going for `summarise` (watch out, you have a typo in `var1_n_pct`). Then bind the rows.

```
row_to_add <- df_report %>%
  summarise(Market = "Total",
          n = sum(n),
          var1_y = sum(var1_y), 
          var1_n = sum(var1_n), 
          total = sum(total),
          var1_y_pct = sum(var1_y_pct),
          var1_n_pct = sum(var1_n_pct), 
          pct_total = sum(pct_total))

df_report %>% bind_rows(row_to_add)
```